# Jetty web server is automatically shutting down on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jetty

I have Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031 is running on EC2 Ubuntu 12.04. It shuts down automatically around in 3 HOURS after it is started. Just to confirm that it is not the issue of my code I removed war file from the server and started with default [spdy.war and test.war] but the same outcome. It got shut down after 3 hours. Jetty does not log any error in the log. Just to mention that this issue started a month ago, before that it was working fine.

### LOG -

Web server Started-

```
2016-11-28 18:00:30.694:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031 2016-11-28     18:00:30.712:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor   /opt/jetty/webapps at interval 1 2016-11-28
18:00:30.718:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added:  /opt/jetty/webapps/test.war 2016-11-28 18:00:30.748:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war!/ to
/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-/webapp 2016-11-28 18:00:31.594:INFO:oejs.TransparentProxy:TransparentProxy @ /test/javadoc-proxy to http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-
8/apidocs 2016-11-28 18:00:31.594:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war 2016-11-28 18:00:31.596:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract
jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war!/ to /mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp 2016-11-28 18:00:31.677:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /opt/jetty/contexts at
interval 1 2016-11-28 18:00:31.678:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /opt/jetty/contexts/javadoc.xml 2016-11-28 18:00:31.709:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started
SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Just idle. No logging in between

Stopped automatically after 3 hours-

```
2016-11-28 21:11:27.567:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 2016-11-28 21:11:27.567:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext
{/test,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war 2016-11-28 21:11:27.568:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext
{/spdy,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war 2016-11-28 21:11:27.568:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler
{/javadoc,file:/opt/jetty/javadoc/} 2016-11-28 21:11:28.589:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{/javadoc,file:/opt/jetty/javadoc/} 2016-11-28
21:11:28.601:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:javax.el.BeanELResolver purged 2016-11-28 21:11:28.601:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/spdy,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-
spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war 2016-11-28 21:11:28.664:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:javax.el.BeanELResolver purged 2016-11-28 21:11:28.665:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/test,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war
```

Comment: Please format your post properly - four spaces before logs makes them easier to read. This is a software problem not an infrastructure problem, you should post it on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Already posted on stackoverflow.com. Someone there suggested to post it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050427/jetty-web-server-is-automatically-shutting-down-very-frequently-on-ec2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started jetty ignoring the hangup signal and this work around seems to be working as of now.  I started jetty with this command [nohup java -jar start.jar &]. But root cause of shut down signal is still away from my sight.